# Scheduling a task using PowerShell without manually creating a task in windows task scheduler

Tags: powershell, taskscheduler

I have written a PowerShell script that I want to run in a daily basis. I want now to create an alert for the same in the system.

But since this needs to be done in not only my computer but also in my teammates' computers (around 10 computers) I was thinking whether it is possible to write a script that when it runs, it automatically schedules a task in the system.

Comment: There is a module: PSScheduledJob please see this tutorial by msdn scripting guy: [https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/09/18/create-a-powershell-scheduled-job/]

Comment: @jkdba that link comes up missing document; .krisnha why the scheduled task, would it only send the message and nothing else?

Comment: @SqlACID Yes.. task scheduler only needs to give an alert message to run the script. Is there any other method in power-shell other than using task scheduler?

Comment: Rather than trying to push something to client computers, if they're all on same domain just shell out or wrap a call to NET SEND MESSAGE; or use something like Growl to handle the messaging; or send an SMS message?; I'm sure you could do the scheduled task but it seems like a complicated approach.